# ArcMap blurry after update from 10.4 to 10.5

Tags: arcgis-10.5, resolution

I had to recently update ArcGIS from 10.4 to 10.5 because of a new license. 
In the new version everything looks a little "blurry".
All other programs (Word, Excel etc) look fine. Even in ArcMap the very top showing the project name (e.g. "New Project - Arc Map") looks fine. I guess thats from Windows. 
Please see the picture, I hope the difference between the very top and the menu is notable. It is very annoying when working for hours in the program.
[image]
Nothing else was changed regarding monitors, resolution etc!

Comment: Could be the dpi settings: https://support.microsoft.com/sv-se/help/2900023/some-desktop-applications-may-appear-blurred-on-high-dpi-displays

Comment: That was it!! The tick at "Disable Display Scaling On High DPI Settings" did the trick. There might be other problems like truncated text and incorrectly sized graphical elements but until now everything seems fine.
Thank you BERA!

Comment: @BERA you should submit that as an answer so it can be accepted, IIRC ArcGIS is one of the few apps that has this problem with Windows settings and I'm guessing it will continue to have it as long as ArcMap 10.x exists.

Answer (score 4):

[Try disabling Dpi virtualization](https://support.microsoft.com/sv-se/help/2900023/some-desktop-applications-may-appear-blurred-on-high-dpi-displays)

> right-click the application’s shortcut and then click Properties. On
>   the Compatibility tab, select Disable Display Scaling On High DPI
>   Settings, and then click OK.